# Changing onfocus with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, text, input, onfocus

I have a conditional statement that does this if a condition is met.
My if statement is fine, everything else works perfectly.
The idea is that if a certain checkbox is ticked, one of the text input will be set to a certain value and become uneditable. I am having problems with this line. Is there a better way to do this? I cannot figure out what's wrong!

```
document.getElementById('amount').onfocus = "this.blur()";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about disabling it

```
document.getElementById('amount').disabled = true;
```

or making it read only

```
document.getElementById('amount').readOnly = true;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GqeUW/)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
onFocus = function(){return false;}
```

or you can use the readonly attribute in your input tag. But i'm not sure if it work in all browsers.